# Type '{ domain: string; parent: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to TS, so thanks for reading.
The problem line is : `<this.RenderPostLink domain={r.domain} parent={r.parent} />` where I get this error.

```
    RenderImages = (): React.ReactElement => (
        <div className="results_wrapper">
            {this.state.results.map(r=>(
                <RenderPanel panelType={PanelType.large} title={r.domain+'.TheCommonVein.net'} preview={(openIt)=>(
                    
                    <div className="result" onClick={openIt} style={{ boxShadow: theme.effects.elevation8}}>
                        <img src={r.url} />
                    </div>
                )}>
                    <div className="panel_wrapper">
                        <div className="panel_content">{r.content}</div>
                        <img src={r.url} />
                        {console.log('wtf'+r.parent)}
                        <this.RenderPostLink domain={r.domain} parent={r.parent} />
                    </div>
                </RenderPanel>
            ))}
        </div>
    )

    RenderPostLink = (domain:string, parent:string) => {
        console.log(parent+domain)
        let url:string
        if(domain=='main'){
            url= 'http://thecommonvein.net/?page='+parent;
        } else {
            url = 'http://'+domain+'.thecommonven.net/?page='+parent;
        }
        return (
            <div>
                {url}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: please publish minimum reproducible example in typescript playground

Comment: Please make sure to construct a [mre]. Note that all three of those words are important: it should be an *example* only, you should not post your entire actual code, rather you should create a simplified example that demonstrates your problem. Also, it should be *minimal*, i.e. it should not contain anything that is not absolutely required to demonstrate the problem. (Most beginner problems can be demonstrated in less than 5 short simple lines of code.) And it should be *reproducible*, which means that if I copy&paste and run the code, I should see the exact same problem you see.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Answer (score 0):

The `RenderPostLink` function is wrong.
You are defining it as a function, but using as a component. The first argument is the object with the props.
The right way would be something like:

```
RenderPostLink = ({domain, parent} :{ domain:string, parent:string)) => ...
```